# How to fit a beta distribution in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, statistics

I am working with a simple dataset and for reproducibility reasons, I am sharing it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10y6KBr5YBy0Pa0JMY_S6PD03qYoe5Tmm).

To make it clear of what I am doing - from column 2, I am reading the current row and compare it with the value of the previous row. If it is greater, I keep comparing. If the current value is smaller than the previous row's value, I want to divide the current value (smaller) by the previous value (larger). Accordingly, the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

protocols = {}

types = {"data_v": "data_v.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
    leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds]/trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    protocols[protname] = {
        "col_time": col_time,
        "col_window": col_window,
        "quotient_times": quotient_times,
        "quotient": quotient,
    }
    plt.figure(); plt.clf()
    diff=quotient_times
    plt.plot(diff,beta_value, ".", label=protname, color="blue")
    plt.ylim(0, 1.0001)
    plt.title(protname)
    plt.xlabel("quotient_times")
    plt.ylabel("quotient")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    sns.distplot(quotient, hist=False, label=protname)
```

This gives the following plots.

[image]

[image]

As we can see from the plots

- **Data-V** has a quotient of 0.8 when the `quotient_times` is less than 3 and the quotient remains 0.5 if the `quotient_times` is
  greater than 3.

Based on this, how can we fit this data into a `beta` like distribution when the `quetient_times` is less than 3 and greater than 3? Intuitively, when the `quetient_times` is less than 3, the distribution peak will be centered around 0.8. When the `quetient_times` is around 3 or 3.05, the peak will be between 0.8 and 0.5 (50%, 50%). However, when the `quetient_times` is greater than 3, the peak will be centered only around 0.5. How can we do this in Python?

Comment: Try looking here, since this seems to have been answered. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68983/beta-distribution-fitting-in-scipy

Comment: I saw that while ago but not helping as much. I would appreciate if you could give it a try and thank you.

Comment: Can you simplify your example data to just the data you are trying to fit the distribution to as a simpler version of the question. Seems like your code already works for what you want to do with the raw data.

Comment: I have never learned about beta distributions, but maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68983/beta-distribution-fitting-in-scipy would be of some help

Comment: I don't have access to the data. Can you somehow provide the access to the data?